# Trying to add Checkbox to a Contact indicating they have a Community account

Tags: customer-community

How can I add a checkbox to a Contact record that will be checked if the Contact has a Community Account?

I want to be able to use this checkbox to determine what to display in an email to customers via an email template.

The User object has a Boolean field named isPortalEnabled but the Contact object doe not have a similar field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach would be to create a field and a process builder on user object:

Object of process: User (When created or updating)

Criteria: ContactId != Null

When to fire: Only fire when relative changed are made to the record(under advanced in the criteria)

Immediate Actions: Update

Records: Select Related object: Contact Id
Field to update isCommunityUser__c value = True

Criteria:
[image: here's the criteria:]

Field Update:
[image: here's a screenshot of the immediate update action]

Comment: This method would get me the information I am looking for but the question is how can I put the results onto the Contacts Record Detail page layout without making the page a Visualforce page or even adding a VF section to the page layout? I would like to figure out a solution that puts the results into a custom field on the Contact sObject so it could then be used in logic within an email template. The information below the System.debug line is not of use for this request

Comment: You would basically need to have a checkbox field on the Contact object, and then create a trigger on the User object that sets the value of that field to the contact, let me know if you need guidance with that i'll write you the trigger.

Comment: An easy approach would be to create a field and a process builder on user object:
Object of process: User
Criteria: ContactId != Null 
When to fire:  Only fire when relative changed are made to the record(under advanced in the criteria)
Immediate Actions: Update Records:
Select Related object: Contact Id
Field to update isCommunityUser__c value = True

Comment: Thanks Haytham.  Take out everything below the last Process Builder image and I will test the Process Builder idea and if it works I can then mark that as the best answer.

Comment: You're welcome
done :)